# How to find bounds when doing a double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

$$\iint e^{x+y}\,dA$$

domain defined by:$$\{x\ge 5\:\:\:,\:y\ge 5\:\:,\:x+y\le 16\}$$

This is what I'm given and I'm asked to solve this.

I know the formula $a\le x\le b\:\:,\:g_1\left(x\right)\le y\le g_2\left(x\right)$.

But I'm not sure how I would find those components.

I got this so far:

$$a=5, b=16$$

And I'm not sure what $g_1(x)$ or the other g is.

How would I find that?

Comment: May be $y$ a function of $x$. If you know that, you can find the bound of $y$. There is not sufficient info to solve this.

Comment: @MathLover woops, i mistyped one of the inequalities. sorry

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of the region?

Comment: @HansLundmark yea i drew lines x=5 y=5 and y=-x+16

Comment: Good, then you should be above the line $y=5$ and below the line $y=-x+16$, right? That tells you what $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are.

Comment: awesome, so 5 and -x+16 are my bounds respectively? thanks!

Comment: Note that $x$ can't go above $11$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sketch of those limits. For $x\ge 5$, draw a vertical line at that value, and you know that your domain is to the right. For $y\ge 5$, draw a horizontal line at $y=5$, and your domain is above that line. Similarly, $x+y=16$ is a line that connects $(16,0)$ and $(0,16)$, and your domain is below that.

With this information, your domain is a triangle. Calculate the intersection points. You should get the vertices at $(5,5)$, $(5,11)$ and $(11,5)$. Then $x$ varies between $5$ and $11$, and $y$ varies between $5$ and $16-x$. Or, if you change the order of integration, $y$ varies between $5$ and $11$, and $x$ between $5$ and $16-x$.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation!